# linking <iostream.h> in linux using gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm trying to run my very first c++ program in linux (linux mint 8). I use either gcc or g++, both with the same problem: the compiler does not find the  library I am trying to import.

I suspect something like I should either copy the iostream.h file (which I don't know where to look for) in the working folder, move my file to compile somewhere else or use an option of some sort.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Here's the gcc command, the c++ code, and the error message:

```
gcc -o addition listing2.5.c
```

.

```
#include <iostream.h>

int Addition(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Resultat : " << Addition(2, 4) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
listing2.5.c:1:22: error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
listing2.5.c: In function ‘main’:
listing2.5.c:10: error: ‘cout’ undeclared (first use in this function)
listing2.5.c:10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
listing2.5.c:10: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Now the code compiles, but I cannot run it from the command line using the file name. `addition: command not found` Any suggestion?

Comment: Surprise!  They went and changed the language in incompatible ways.  That was nice of them.

Comment: @Eric: Who is "they", and what did they "change" ?

Comment: I don't code in C++ often enough to know or care who's in charge of C++ standards.  But I once had the same experience as Morlock, of coming back to C++ after many years and discovering that `#includes` no longer use `.h` and `cin`/`cout` went and hid inside `std::`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- `cout` is defined in the std:: namespace, you need to use `std::cout` instead of just `cout`.
- You should also use `#include <iostream>` not the old `iostream.h`
- use g++ to compile C++ programs, it'll link in the standard c++ library. gcc will not. gcc will also compile your code as C code if you give it a .c suffix. Give your files a .cpp suffix.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I guess I'll trow away the 2000 book I'm learning with. :)

Comment: Hum, the "addition" file created does not work. I try to use it from the command line, writing: addition, but it says "command not found". I also tried to click on it and no terminal pops up. How could I make it work?

Comment: The current directory isn't in your path.  Try `./addition`

Answer (score 6):

please use g++ not gcc to compile it

Comment: You really need to provide more information than this. (Why g++ should be used for example.)

Comment: g++ and gcc is the same compiler but with different frontend. One of this difference is that g++ with link with C++ standard libraries (like <iostream> your are using) and not the gcc frontend.

Answer (score 5):

You need `<iostream>` not `<iostream.h>`.

They are also header files not libraries.

Other things to fix, `cout` should be `std::cout` and you should use `std::endl` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: No, using `"\n"` is better.  I think you are aware that `std::endl` flushes the stream also.

Answer (score 3):

You need `<iostream>`, `<iostream.h>` is non-standard too-old header. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int Addition(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Resultat : " << Addition(2, 4) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use **std** alongside **cout** as below-

`std::cout << "Hello World";`

You can also define **std** at beginning of program by '*using namespace*' keywords as-

```
     #include <iostream >

     using namespace std;

    int Addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Result : " << Addition(2, 4) << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Now you need not to write std,everytime you use I/O operations.